# How to deal with multiple tabs, EditText and save to database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

I am creating a Cash Sales app where I will implement 4 tabs. From 1st tab user will select customer from customer list, 2nd tab to select item from item list, 3rd tab to set payment details in 7 `EditText`'s and 4th to view draft and confirm to save in SQLite. I have couple of questions on it:

1. For tab, should I create a tab container first by extending `FragmentActivity` like following:

   ```
   public class CashSales extends FragmentActivity {

       private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           setContentView(R.layout.cash_sales_tab);
           mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
           mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

           mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("customer").setIndicator("customer"),
                   CustomerSelect.class, null);
           mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("item").setIndicator("item"),
                   ItemSelect.class, null);
           mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("payment").setIndicator("payment"),
                   SetPayment.class, null);
           mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("payment").setIndicator("payment"),
                   DraftViewAndSave.class, null);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Should I create different classes for each of the activities like `CustomerSelect`, `ItemSelect` etc? If need to create different classes should it be extended from `Fragment` class or `FragmentActivity` class?
3. How can I memorize the data when user will go from 1st tab to 2nd tab? Should I use Session and finally save data from session to database?

Guys I am new in Android. Please help me on this or send any sample link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented the same thing so I am sharing my thoughts.

```
For tab, should I create a tab container first by extending FragmentActivity
```

You should create a class which extend the `FragmentActivity` . But rather using tabs I used `ViewPager` and custome `FragmentPagerAdapter` which hold your four different `Fragnment` (in your case CustomerSelect,ItemSelect etc) and on swipe You can save the data in `Bundle` in your Fragments and then call a `public` method from your FragmentActivity to get `Bundle` Object from your `fragment` classes

`Should I create different classes for each of the activities like CustomerSelect, ItemSelect etc?`

Yes you should.

`How can I memorize the data when user will go from 1st tab to 2nd tab? Should I use Session and finally save data from session to database?`

As describe above you can save the data in bundle object and then in your FragmentActivity you can call your save method in `onPageSelected` method like .

```
private Bundle firstFragmentData;

  mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {

                switch (arg0) {
                case 1:

                    fragment1 = (MyFirstFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .findFragmentByTag(
                                    "android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":"
                                            + (arg0 - 1));
                    firstFragmentData = fragment1.SaveDatainFragment1();

                    break;
```

Actually you need to set the `getters` for your all bundle objects which you get from different fragments in your main FragmentActivity like

```
public Bundle getFirstFragmentData() {
     return firstFragmentData;  
 }
```

Now In your any Fragment you can get any Fragment data like this..

```
Bundle firstFragmentData = ((MainFragmentActivity) getActivity())
                        .getFirstFragmentData(); // here you got the bundle
```

I hope this helps.